# Simple Question on Pointers

Tags: c

Can someone remind me why this works?

A function requiring int* could take as input an (obviously)

```
int *integer;
```

but it could also accept

```
&var->integer
```

with var being var_t*, where var_t:

```
typedef struct {
    int integer;
} var_t;
```

why is the 2nd accepted?

edit: oopsy, question is same but var is actually a var_t* (and not a var_t) to be more precise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break it down.

`var` is a `var_t*`.

`var->integer` is an `int`.

`&var->integer` is an `int*`.

Comment: That's the way I like to think.

Answer (score 3):

The second version is accepted because of the [ampersand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) at the beginning. This means that the address of the field is passed, not the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of var is `var_t`, the code you've shown is actually illegal. If its type is `var_t*`, it's accepted because the type of `var->integer` is `int` and the type of `&some_int` is `int*`.

Comment: True; true; question is same  but it must had been more accurate on the real world root of it. [edited and added it's actually var_t*).

Answer (score 0):

2nd version of code is only good version, because you must use & operator to get address of integer in var_t structure.

Answer (score 0):

Do the math your self:

```
int a => &a is of type int*
int *a => &a is of type int**
int **a => &a is of type int***
```

etc.

```
int *a => *a is of type int
int **a => a is of type int**
int **a => *a is of type int*
int **a => **a is of type int
```